# Create an inspector style window using Swing/AWT

Tags: java, macos, swing, user-interface, awt

Is there a way to create a window using Swing or AWT that behaves and looks like an inspector window on Mac OS X? An example of an inspector window would be the window that opens in Finder when `Command`-`Option`-`I` is pressed.

I'm looking for a way to create a window that has a half-height title bar, that always stays on top and that does not get focus e.g. when dragged around.

It is only necessary for the solution to work on Mac OS X, so platform-specific libraries are allowed. But if there is a standard way, event if it has minor drawbacks, it is preferred.

Comment: You might look at the [`macwidgets`](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/) project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leopard added some Swing client properties to improve the UI of OS X Java apps – these are described in [Technical Note TN2196](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html). The one you're looking for is [Window.style](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html#WINDOW_STYLE):

> This property determines if the window has a Utility-style title bar. In order to make this window style also float above all others you must additionally call setAlwaysOnTop(true). Windows that have both the "small" style and are set to always be on top will automatically hide themselves when your application is no longer frontmost. This is similar to how native applications behave.

This property has to be set on the [JRootPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) of a window before it's native peer is created:

```
dialog.getRootPane().putClientProperty("Window.style", "small");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and then some! Could I suggest that you add a representative line to your answer, showing how the desired effect is achieved?  I don't trust the linked article to have the same URL two years from now, when I'm coming back to this question because I forgot in which project I already had a solution to that problem. It currently looks like this in my code: `dialog.getRootPane().putClientProperty("Window.style", "small");`

Answer (score 1):

ModalityTypes are platform dependent, you have to look for [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html)#[ModalityTypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html)

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Java SE 7 isn't officially supported on OS X.

Comment: What do modality types have to do with the OP's question? He's looking for how to make inspectors, not sheets, and I don't think Window-modal dialogs appear as sheets anyway.

Comment: *"Java SE 7 isn't officially supported on OS X."* So what?  Any J7 docs. that are new to J7 should be marked @since J7.  The point is that the 7 docs are available, so to help Google find version 7 (rather than 1.4.2, which is typical) docs, let's start using the 7 links.  (Or at least until that RFE linked in my first comment is implemented - at which point it will all become moot.  Care to add a vote?)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - on a quest? <g> 'new to J7 should be marked since J7' true in an ideal world, false in reality (f.i. it's nowhere mentioned that ListModel is generified since 7) Personaly, I dont much care except hating the new doc appeareance: low contrast colors, bluish to make them even harder to read, silly spacial ordering which makes it even harder to see the _method_ names at a glance ... but that's a different fight, simply couldn't resist :-)

Comment: @kleopatra *"on a quest?"*  Call me Don Quixote.  *"but that's a different fight.."*  You vote for mine, and the minute your RFE appears, I'll vote for yours.  ( hint, hint ;)